# Bootstrap 4 cards keeps scaling instead of adjusting within the fixed area

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get some functionality to work with bootstrap 4 cards but I keep having trouble as it keeps scaling with the length of text. My code is as below

```
<div class="row row-container">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Heading</h5>
                <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Heading</h5>
                <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Heading</h5>
                <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-container">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    Heading</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you look at the last card it basically takes up an entire column pushing all the elements. Is there any way I can fit the content of a card to within the card only?

Really appreciate you support

Answer (score 0):

Add **Margin** and fixed **height** and **width** to your cards! That's may fix your problem

or you can change bootstrap class **col to col-4** witch gives you exact same size 3 columns

```
 <div class="container ">
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        Heading</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        Heading</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        Heading</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">SomeText</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-4 offset-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        Heading</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an
                        unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
                        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
                        containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                        Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Maneesha. Doin so leaves a lot of empty space in the middle
anything I can do about it ?

Comment: @devz plx clearly mention your requirement ill solve that

Comment: for more ref - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Through looking at your code, the main reason that the card keeps scaling because you don't set the fixed width to the card. You can look into this Bootstrap 4 grid system https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp for more info about how to divide fixed width to elements.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
  <div class="col-*-*"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want the card to stay in the middle of the page, you should look into Bootstrap 4 Flex https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp